# How to change the text of a tabPanel using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, tabpanel

Is it possible to change the text of a page of a tabPanel and/or to setVisible() in a UiApp using GAS?

**EDIT-1**
To clarify my question :

```
function doGet()
{
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();
   var tabPanel = app.createTabPanel().setId('AAA');  

   var horPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('XXX').setSize(500, 400);
   tabPanel.add(horPanel, 'YYY');

   app.add(tabPanel);
   return app;
}
```

I want to change change the text 'YYY' into something else at any time after the user sees the panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The individual panels are not available as separate objects, you can't change their properties neither hide them individually so I'm afraid what you are trying won't be possible.

The only thing you can do is select one of them, that's about all.

To get the same functionality I use vertical panels and handlers like [in this example](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxlPTVLSLfO3d1w2vSrMzzh57p9DJM6ivCIHiIfTB2AKqubSs1L/exec)... it is entirely composed of "normal" panels and I can do what I want with it...

EDIT : handlers to switch panels :

```
//Panel Handlers
  var pHandler1 = app.createClientHandler()
  .forEventSource().setStyleAttribute('color','blue')
  .forTargets(mainPanel[0]).setVisible(true)
  .forTargets(mainPanel[1],mainPanel[2],mainPanel[3]).setVisible(false)
  .forTargets(button[1],button[2],button[3]).setStyleAttribute('color','white')
  button[0].addClickHandler(pHandler1)

  var pHandler2 = app.createClientHandler()
  .forEventSource().setStyleAttribute('color','blue')
  .forTargets(mainPanel[1]).setVisible(true)
  .forTargets(mainPanel[0],mainPanel[2],mainPanel[3]).setVisible(false)
  .forTargets(button[0],button[2],button[3]).setStyleAttribute('color','white')
  button[1].addClickHandler(pHandler2)

  var pHandler3 = app.createClientHandler()
  .forEventSource().setStyleAttribute('color','blue')
  .forTargets(mainPanel[2]).setVisible(true)
  .forTargets(mainPanel[0],mainPanel[1],mainPanel[3]).setVisible(false)
  .forTargets(button[0],button[1],button[3]).setStyleAttribute('color','white')
  button[2].addClickHandler(pHandler3)

  var pHandler4 = app.createClientHandler()
  .forEventSource().setStyleAttribute('color','blue')
  .forTargets(mainPanel[3]).setVisible(true)
  .forTargets(mainPanel[0],mainPanel[1],mainPanel[2]).setVisible(false)
  .forTargets(button[0],button[1],button[2]).setStyleAttribute('color','white')
  button[3].addClickHandler(pHandler4)
```

image of another app using this feature :

[image]

Comment: I was afraid so.  I saw that example before, but (despite its functionality) it doesn't look as nice compared to the standard panels. I have been thinking about creating background images for it and using your example, but I did not investigate that. Great if you improve it !!

Comment: Yes, its could be improved but I have other versions that look better... I'll edit my answer with image and the client handlers I use.

Comment: as a hack, I add a first tab with the label 'hide' which has nothing but a blank label set to the width needed for the entire panel. you can select that manually or programmatically to hide the other tabs and reduce the amount of screen used. the animation effect is pleasing too :)

Comment: @SergeInsas This version looks very well. For sure I will have a look at its potential ! Thx

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this not by adding strings to the tab, but used a Label instead.  I could use the id of the label later to tweak the content.

```
  var horPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('XXX').setSize(500, 400);
  var horLabel = app.createLabel('YYY').setStyleAttributes({fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'red'}).setId('xxxLabel');
  tabPanel.add(horPanel, horLabel);
```

In the call back:

```
  var callBackHorLabel = app.getElementById('xxxLabel');
  callBackHorLabel.setText('ZZZ').setStyleAttributes({color: 'inherit'});
```

There may be better ways to deal with the CSS of created label to make it match the default label, but I was too lazy to research it.  Hence, the fontWeight.

Comment: I couldn't get that working. Maybe because you didn't understand the question well. because of that I edited my question.

Comment: I did understand it, I just messed up my example with adding content to the tabPanel.  Sorry about that.

I redid the code to match up with your example.